# Aiogram. Уникальность фото

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть ли какая-то возможность определения уникальности фото (картинки), отсылаемой боту?

То есть, пользователь высылает боту фото, и перед тем как сохранить его в БД (у меня сохранение по file_id), бот должен убедиться, что этот файл не высылался ранее. Пробовал по file_id, не вариант. Каждый раз присваивается новый ID.

Возможно есть какие-то способы реализовать данную идею?

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, вычислять вектор изображения с помощью нейронной сети и рассчитывать процент его уникальности путём сравнения с другими векторами из вашей БД используя алгоритмы подобия, к примеру, косинусное сходство.

Если вы хотите вычислять уникальность любых файлов, а не только картинок, то единственный полностью рабочий способ - хранить в БД весь файл целиком (что глупо). Как костыль, можно сравнивать размер файлов и их хеш, но эффективность подобного способа будет крайне далека от идеала.

Comment: Ух, ну это точно не мой уровень, пока что. В любом случае спасибо.